# how can I read a email with clj-mail

Tags: clojure, jakarta-mail

mail to send/read emails but some have the next form:

```
#:clj-mail.core.Email{:subject "xxxxx", :content #<MimeMultipart javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@3d01e178>, :sent #<Date Tue Apr 05 19:02:55 CDT 2011>, :received nil, :from ("=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Xxxx_D=EDXx?= <xxxx@xx.com>"), :recipients ("xxx@xxx.com"), :reply-to ("=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Xxxx_D=Xxx?= <xxxx@xxxx>")}
```

and i don't know how can read the part of :content to extract the text of the message

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you paste, it looks like body is of type [MimeMultiPart](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart.html). Get the parts using getBodyPart and read the ones the are text/plain.

Comment: thanks!!!!!
now I have the next problem, with the attachments, is something like com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream. exist some way to get the item?